# Airflow : how to deliver data from parent dag to sub dag (by xcom or other ways)

Tags: airflow

Initially, I wanted to deliver value from parent DAG to a subdag by `xcom_push`/`xcom_pull` (Airflow provided functions), but I found it has no effect after trying so many times.

Can someone help me to implement value delivering between parent dag and subdag?

Here's my business code. I just want to deliver `daily_check` from parent dag to sub dag.

```py
# function used by parent DAG
def templated_daily_check(ds, **kwargs):
   hour_2_check_daily = kwargs['hour_2_check_daily']
   zk_hosts = kwargs['zk_hosts']
   zk_path_daily = kwargs['zk_path_daily']
   check_time = kwargs['check_time']
   # invoke custom python function dailyCheck to get zookeeper data
   dailyOrNot = dailyTask.dailyCheck(zk_hosts, zk_path_daily, hour_2_check_daily, check_time)
   print ("=====================================================================================================>")
   print (dailyOrNot)
   # daily_check:data that need to be transferred to subdag
   kwargs['ti'].xcom_push(key='daily_check', value=dailyOrNot)
   if dailyOrNot:
       dailyTask.dailyMark(zk_hosts, zk_path_daily, check_time)

# function to create sub DAG
def sub_dag_iaoc_or_iaocPlusaauoo(parent_dag_name, child_dag_name, all_task_name):
    subDag = DAG(
        dag_id='%s.%s' % (parent_dag_name, child_dag_name),
        default_args=default_argsi, schedule_interval=timedelta(hours=dag_duration_hours)
    )
    # daily_check:data that need to be received from parent dag,and my way to receive data from parent dag as follows,but not effect
    daily_check = os.popen('''echo {{ task_instance.xcom_pull(task_ids='daily_check_bf_all', key='daily_check', dag_id=%s) }}''' % (parent_dag_name)).read()
    # Based on the values received above,to determine the number of operators generated
    if daily_check == str(False):
        t_r_fm_all_iaoc = BashOperator(
            task_id='r_fm_all_iaoc',
            bash_command= """{}/fm/sh/airflow_preparerun_task.sh {} {} r_fm_all_iaoc""".format(USER_HOME_FOLDER, trade_jar_rev, USER_HOME_FOLDER) + ";" +
                          """{} {} {} {} {} {} -r {} -iaoc """.format(spark_submit_fixed_conf, yarn_res_fixed_args, trade_class_fm, '{}/fm/jar/{}/fmtrade-{}.jar'.format(USER_HOME_FOLDER, 'r_fm_all_iaoc', trade_jar_rev), trade_fixed_args, trade_task_fixed_args_fm, all_task_name),
            dag=subDag
        )
    else:
        t_r_fm_all_iaoc = BashOperator(
            task_id='r_fm_all_iaoc',
            bash_command= """{}/fm/sh/airflow_preparerun_task.sh {} {} r_fm_all_iaoc""".format(USER_HOME_FOLDER, trade_jar_rev, USER_HOME_FOLDER) + ";" +
                          """{} {} {} {} {} {} -r {} -iaoc """.format(spark_submit_fixed_conf, yarn_res_fixed_args, trade_class_fm, '{}/fm/jar/{}/fmtrade-{}.jar'.format(USER_HOME_FOLDER, 'r_fm_all_iaoc', trade_jar_rev), trade_fixed_args, trade_task_fixed_args_fm, all_task_name),
            dag=subDag
        )
        t_r_fm_all_aauoo = BashOperator(
            task_id='r_fm_all_aauoo',
            bash_command= """{}/fm/sh/airflow_preparerun_task.sh {} {} r_fm_all_aauoo""".format(USER_HOME_FOLDER, trade_jar_rev, USER_HOME_FOLDER) + ";" +
                          """{} {} {} {} {} {} -r {} -aauoo """.format(spark_submit_fixed_conf, yarn_res_fixed_args, trade_class_fm, '{}/fm/jar/{}/fmtrade-{}.jar'.format(USER_HOME_FOLDER, 'r_fm_all_aauoo', trade_jar_rev), trade_fixed_args, trade_task_fixed_args_fm_all, all_task_name),
            dag=subDag
        )
    return subDag

t_daily_check_bf_all = PythonOperator(
   task_id='daily_check_bf_all',
   provide_context=True,
   python_callable=templated_daily_check,
   op_kwargs={
       'hour_2_check_daily': hour_2_check_daily,
       'zk_hosts': zk_hosts,
       'zk_path_daily': zk_path_daily,
       "check_time":  time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', time.localtime(time.time()))
   },
   dag=dag
)

t_r_fm_all_subdag = SubDagOperator(
   subdag=sub_dag_iaoc_or_iaocPlusaauoo('afFMTradeDag',
                  'iaoc_or_iaocPlusaauoo',
                  'all'),
   task_id='iaoc_or_iaocPlusaauoo',
   dag=dag
)
```

Comment: What have you tried "many times"?